# What is an analog of HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In old ASP.NET we had HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase which represent the current user's browser capabilities.
In WebApi it can be acquired from `HttpRequestMessage.HttpRequestHeaders.UserAgent`.

What is an analog of HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase in ASP.NET 5

Answer (score 0):

You can reach out to `User-Agent` header from [`HttpRequest.Headers`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/e818783ba4b818542a681be4a206dc40804c33a6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/HttpRequest.cs#L77) collection. You can also take advantage of handy [`HeaderNames`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/e818783ba4b818542a681be4a206dc40804c33a6/src/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers/HeaderNames.cs) constants.

Comment: Sure, user-agent string can be easily extracted from request. But HBC did some parsing. Also there was config settings for browsers/versions capabilities mapped to their ua names.

Comment: @Shrike yes, they are gone now IIRC and I suspect they will ever come back on ASP.NET 5 world.